In NodeRED, how do I count the number of arrays that have a similar value in the 4th position using a function node
In NodeRED, I need to use a function node to count the number of arrays inside the larger array for which the 4th value is "Yes" and return that number as the payload.
I'm stuck on how to loop through this and get that value.
This is being pulled from a google sheet.  The sheet is an array, and each row is another array.
[
    ["2024-03-30 9:25:38","2024-03-30T09:25:36.647Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","Yes"],
    ["2024-03-30 11:07:15","2024-03-30T11:07:13.972Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-03-30 13:21:26","2024-03-30T13:21:24.432Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-02 17:05:23","2024-04-02T17:05:20.468Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-03 11:47:55","2024-04-03T11:47:47.277Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-05 19:19:38","2024-04-05T19:19:37.735Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-05 19:43:45","2024-04-05T19:43:43.067Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-06 8:24:01","2024-04-06T08:23:59.429Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-06 14:04:00","2024-04-06T14:03:59.291Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-06 18:13:37","2024-04-06T18:13:35.459Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-08 17:34:19","2024-04-08T17:34:17.239Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-08 21:47:34","2024-04-08T21:47:32.868Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-10 18:52:11","2024-04-10T18:52:10.138Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-11 18:01:17","2024-04-11T18:01:15.296Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-04-22 8:36:45","2024-04-22T08:36:42.964Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-04-22 8:37:23","2024-04-22T08:37:21.933Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-06 17:16:08","2024-05-06T17:16:06.432Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-09 14:39:28","2024-05-09T14:39:26.669Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-09 14:41:06","2024-05-09T14:41:05.029Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-11 18:48:12","2024-05-11T18:48:10.139Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-29 16:51:18","2024-05-29T16:51:16.836Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-05-30 16:07:36","2024-05-30T16:07:33.431Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-05-31 15:06:16","2024-05-31T15:06:15.495Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"],
    ["2024-05-31 19:13:45","2024-05-31T19:13:44.829Z","0b0633067a0041a39ae7d0502d25303a","No"],
    ["2024-05-31 20:11:35","2024-05-31T20:11:34.247Z","c9ea5f917bc74975b65dcbc656614308","No"]
]


loop using a for loop, or Array.forEach, or Array.map or Array.reduce or Array.reduceRight as appropriate to your end requirements ... the 4th element of an array is at index 3 ... hope that all helps you to try and write some actual code

What have you tried and how did it fail?

Here's what I came up with that produced the result I needed.  I don't know if it's elegant or trashy or bulky...but it works.


var completed = [];                            // create empty array
for (var i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; i++) { // for each row in the spreadsheet
    var answer = msg.payload[i][3];            // store the value of the 4th column
    if (answer == "Yes") {                     // if it's "yes" then
    completed.push(answer);                    // push the value into the new array
    }
};
var yescount = completed.length;               // grab the length of the new array
msg.payload = yescount;                        // assign it to the payload
return msg;                                    // deliver the package.



I'm new at this.  ;).  Let me know if there are more elegant or efficient ways to do this if you feel inclined.

You can use JS array functions for a shorter solution:


const yesCount = msg.payload.filter(arr => arr[3] == "Yes").length
msg.payload = yesCount



I recommend you checking out also other array functions available in JS as they will make your code cleaner and save a lot of hassle handling iterators and indexes.
